# Azure virtual network peering question - why virtual network gateway is not needed when peering two virtual networks? Is the gateway just not needed

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

When I set a virtual network peering solution between two vnets, why is the virtual network gateway is set to none in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: if both VNETs are on azure, you don't need a gateway. You would use a gateway to connect azure vnet to on-prem vnet for example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Answer (score 0):

> [**Virtual network peering**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/vnet-peering#virtual-network-connection-types) connects two Azure virtual networks. Once peered, the virtual networks appear as one for connectivity purposes.

In my environment the virtual network gateway is set to **`none`** after selecting the virtual network as below:

[image]

- The **`None`** option means that traffic from the peered virtual network flow to this Virtual network but can't flow to a Gateway virtual Network.
- The **`Use the remote virtual network's gateway or Route Server`** option means that peered networks use remote virtual network i.e. it peers from the other virtual network.
- The **`Use this virtual network's gateway or Route Server`** option means that allowing traffic from the peered virtual network to the gateway.

*I agree with **Thomas** if both VNets are on azure then gateway isn't needed. Gateways are for connecting azure vnet to on-prem vnet as detailed above.*

> Public internet, gateways, or encryption is not required in the communication between the virtual networks as mentioned in this [**blog**](https://medium.com/awesome-azure/azure-virtual-network-vnet-peering-overview-introduction-a795517bd83b) by **Ashish Patel**.

You can **refer** the below links for more in detail:

[Create, change, or delete an Azure virtual network peering | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering#create-a-peering)

[VNet Peering With Step By Step Dem by Krunal Trivedi](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/vnet-peering-with-step-by-step-demo/)